# What is the point of storing values in a sequence of instances?

Tags: python, class, twitter, flatten

The twitter API layer implementation for python (https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py) at [A Python wrapper around the Twitter API.](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) returns a **sequence of instances** i.e. as return of

```
status=api.GetHomeTimeline().
```

Internally I understand it converts a json list of dicts into that sequence.

I had to fiddle around a little to find out how to read out all the values.

There are a bunch of classes one can read out directly, i.e.:

```
status[0].user.listed_count
```

prints the value. But for i.e. the values under

```
status[0].user_mentions
```

the three variable:value pairs are stored as a list.

Why is that done that way? Is that a common programming technique? Until now I always dealt with nested json dicts/lists, which is way easyer to figure out, as one can iterate over everything.

Comment: If you don't want the wrapper, just don't use the wrapper! If you're more comfortable with JSON that's fine.

Comment: No! I am not critizing it! I am stumbling upon that technique and I never read about it, so I wonder: hey, whats that, is there a paradigm or something about it, where I can learn about it. There must be some special benefit about doing so, as - in my understanding - the api layer has the data in json format first, then converts it do instances.

Comment: That's how API wrappers work, they abstract away the transport layer and let you deal with native representations of the results; in this case, exposing Python objects for users, tweets, etc.

Comment: yeah, but we have dicts and lists in python. are instances of classes another pythonic way to store data?

Comment: Please cf. also my answer but for short: dicts crossing from one host language eg. at server side as JSON in transport into another host language like Python on client side may be troublesome to parse and store as the sequence of keys as they appear on the wire may be changed differently in different host language storage constructs. Deeply nested means you have to digest evetnually many more bytes until you are at a point of interest. flattening subtrees may help here. So maybe users of the wrapper just liked it that way ...

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate answer in this case can only be given by the authors of that implementation.

In general deeply nesting information leads to generic solutions for producers of that information instance, but puts more strain on the consumer (especially a gerneic one) to sort things out as they have been meant.

Here a python API implementation flattens some things so you can iterate over them or as documented in [the API wrapper documentation](http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) itself. You can easily find out - like you maybe did, when I follow your question correctly - which JSON object is being flattedn and in which position is put what, and that you can skip these things entirely, when setting a specific parameter upon request to false.

In my daily work, I am often confronted with concepts suggesting deeply nested trees for information, and in most if not any cases, feedback from architects and users alike leads to flattening of these structures to meet the balance between genericity and preparation for future extension as one extreme and practicality, performance and low cost market penetration here and now.

I hope this was on the right level for answering your question. If not so please feel free to comment ask.